# Pull objects from Parse in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, local-storage

### This is now resolved, the code is correct and worked perfectly with a new class created in Parse.

---

I'm trying to pull objects from Parse and pin them to local storage then pull the objects into a table view. The query seems to be the problem, I've followed numerous tutorials and read documentation and I believe I'm doing the right thing.

The query definitely matches with the Parse database and the link to the database definitely exists as I'm able to log in and create accounts.

Printing the results of the queries prints..

Successfully retrieved 0 jobs from local storage.

Successfully retrieved 0 jobs from database.
The code is as follows

```
import UIKit
import Parse


class JobsTableViewController: UITableViewController, PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate {

    var jobObjects: NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: "handleRefresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    }

    // Mark: When view appears, if a user exists run functions 
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        if (PFUser.currentUser() == nil) {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("checkLogged", sender: self)

        } else {
            self.fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDatastore()
            self.fetchAllObjects()
        }
    }

    // Mark: Fetch all objects from local storage
    func fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDatastore() {

        var query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Jobs")

        query.fromLocalDatastore()

        query.whereKey("Attendants", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                // The find succeeded.
                println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) jobs from local storage.")
                // Do something with the found objects
                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    for object in objects {
                        println(object.objectId)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
            }

        }

    }
    // Mark: Fetch all objects from Parse.
    func fetchAllObjects() {

        PFObject.unpinAllObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)

        var query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Jobs")

        query.whereKey("Author", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                // The find succeeded.
                println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count)  jobs from database.")
                // Do something with the found objects
                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    for object in objects {
                        println(object.objectId)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
            }   
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return self.jobsObjects.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EventsTableViewCell

        var object: PFObject = self.jobObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject

        cell.titleLabel?.text = object["JobName"] as? String
        cell.mainTextLabel?.text = object["Description"] as? String

        return cell
    }

    func handleRefresh(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
        // Do some reloading of data and update the table view's data source
        // Fetch more objects from a web service, for example...

        // Simply adding an object to the data source for this example


        self.tableView.reloadData()
        refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }
}
```

Comment: No it doesn't, neither function retrieves any objects.

Comment: Just to clarify there are definitely objects that match the criteria in the parse class

Comment: Have you ever had a query return objects?

Comment: Can you just remove the 'where' part and see whether at least that works?

Comment: I think I tried removing the where and still failed to retrieve objects. However the app does log in and create accounts

Comment: Please try it again - if that doesn't yield anything there is a) either nothing in there, b) your class name is wrong (usually it would be 'Job' and not 'Jobs'), c) parse is broken - c is rather unlikely

Comment: @NilsZiehn okay thanks, I'll try again when I'm home. Thank you for getting back to me

Comment: Could you attach a print screen of your Parse database console? Just to confirm that the keys and values are correct? Also, how did you create the entries in the database? Did you double check for any whitespace in the keys?

Comment: @Kumuluzz Thanks for getting back to me. I created a new class and linked it to that instead and managed to get an object.